# C++ Error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand

Tags: c++, class, lvalue

I have created a class named node. It is defined as follows:

```
class node
{
    private:
        int key;
        node * next;

    public:
        void setkey(int key);
        void setnext(node * next);
        int getkey();
        node * getnext();
};
```

These functions are basic getter and setter functions.
Now, if I try to do this:

```
MoveNode(&(bTail->getnext()),&start);
```

it shows error as :lvalue required as unary '&' operand

Now, if I update the class Node and keep (node * next) as public and access via this:

```
MoveNode(&(bTail->next),&start);
```

It shows no error.

Please help as to how can I get rid of the error.

Comment: Hello Maulik welcome to stackoverflow! Please take into account the difference between code snippets, and code samples. Talking about c++ code samples will be all you need in general:).

Comment: You probably want `MoveNode(bTail->getnext(), &start)`, but it's hard for us to be sure without seeing what `MoveNode` does with the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return `node*` from `getnext()`, you create a temporary variable of `node*` type, so it has no sense to take its address by using `&`, this temporary variable will anyway be destroyed soon.

When you directly access `next`, you refer to a long-living variable, and you can take its address.

You might want to return a *reference* to `node*` from `getnext()`:

```
node*& getnext() {return next;};
```

so that it will point to the same variable `next` and you will be able to take its address.

Answer (score 1):

```
MoveNode(&(bTail->getnext()),&start);
```

> it shows error as :lvalue required as unary '&' operand

Of course it does. `getnext` returns a temporary value (a copy of the pointer) and temporaries are rvalues. Rvalues don't have an associated memory address, so you may not use them as an oprand for `&`.

```
MoveNode(&(bTail->next),&start);
```

> It shows no error.

Well, `bTail->next` *is* an lvalue, so there is no syntax error there.

If you need to pass into `MoveNode` a pointer to a pointer, then that pointed to pointer must be stored somewhere. Since it's stored as a member in the `node`, you could return a reference instead of a copy of the pointer in which case you'd be returning an lvalue and your syntax would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
MoveNode(&(bTail->getnext()),&start);
```

This doesn't work because you are trying to take the address of a temporary pointer returned by `getnext`. The fact that pointers can be temporary might sound strange at first, but essentially you aren't getting a pointer to where the node stores its `next` pointer, but to some meaningless memory location.

If you want really want `&(bTail->getnext())` to return the address of `next` within that node, make `getnext` return a reference to that pointer:

```
node *& getnext();
```